# How to get matching subdocuments in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have schema like this -

```
 {
   "_id":"ObjectId(""622f950e73043487031bb3ee"")",
   "outerTimeStamp" : "14-Mar-2022",
   "filtered":{
      "data":[
         {
            "Price":14350,
            "expiryDate":"17-Mar-2022",
            "info1":{
               "Price":14350,
               "expiryDate":"17-Mar-2022",
            },
            "info2":{
               "Price":14350,
               "expiryDate":"17-Mar-2022"
            }
         },
         {
            "Price":14350,
            "expiryDate":"17-Mar-2022",
            "info1":{
               "Price":14350,
               "expiryDate":"17-Mar-2022",
            },
            "info2":{
               "Price":14350,
               "expiryDate":"17-Mar-2022"
            }
         },
         ......
         ....
     ]
    }
}
```

I need all the subdocuments from a document where expiryDate == "17-Mar-2022"

I have used the following query -

```
db.collection.find({ "filtered.data" : { $elemMatch : { "expiryDate" : "17-Mar-2022"}} }, { "filtered.data.$" : 1 })
```

it just returns the first matching sub-document but there are many other documents also available

if I don't use ".$" then it returns all those documents even those that don't match with the query conditions.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do simpy by aggregation/$filter:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
  "filtered.data.expiryDate": "17-Mar-2022"
  }
},
{
 $addFields: {
  "filtered.data": {
    "$filter": {
      "input": "$filtered.data",
      "as": "d",
      "cond": {
        "$eq": [
          "$$d.expiryDate",
          "17-Mar-2022"
        ]
       }
     }
    }
  }
 }
])
```

For best results index need to be created on "filtered.data.expiryDate"

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PBaptcqrNSV)

Comment: This query is working fine but it partially solve my issue, is it possible to run mongo DB query on specific document not all all documents present on the index or can it be solved without Agg ?

Comment: I just added one more filter as well in the match then it started working